# Violation of Liskov's Substitution Principle

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles

How is this example below violating Liskov's Substitution Principle? I still can't get my head around it. It seems ok to me in terms of hierarchy in PHP OOP.

```
// Violation of Likov's Substitution Principle
class Rectangle
{
    protected $width;
    protected $height;

    public function setWidth($width){
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function setHeight($height){
        $this->height = $height;
    }


    public function getWidth(){
        return $width;
    }

    public function getHeight(){
        return $height;
    }

    public function getArea(){
        return $this->width * $this->height;
    }   
}

class Square extends Rectangle 
{
    public function setWidth($width){
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $width;
    }

    public function setHeight($height){
        $this->width = $height;
        $this->height = $height;
    }

}
```

usage:

```
$Rectangle = new Rectangle();
$Rectangle->setWidth(5);
$Rectangle->setHeight(10);
echo $Rectangle->getArea(); // 50 --> correct
```

Another:

```
$Rectangle = new Square();
$Rectangle->setWidth(5);
$Rectangle->setHeight(10);
echo $Rectangle->getArea(); // 100 --> correct
```

The reuslt from both are correct.

So, how this code should be written so that it is not violating Liskov's Substitution Principle?

Comment: Because the interface to rectangle allows you to set width and height independently of one another. For Square, setting width to 5 and height to 10 is ambiguous.

Comment: This is a classic problem for the OOP. THere are a lots of solutions for it. Basically, you shouldn't make the base any of the classes, they have a different behaviour.

Comment: You've indicated that an area of 100 is correct for the square, but since the size is ambiguous (sides are both 5 and 10) I don't know if I would call that correct.

Comment: Maybe it would be better in the Square to throw an exception when setting the height? You can only ever set one side, and the input is then clear.

Comment: 10 x 10 = 100 so it is correct. isn't?

Comment: The problem is not the end result but the code that leads to it that suggests something else as you can set width and height, just the first one is discarded.

Comment: @halfer that would also be a violation of liskov: No new exceptions should be thrown by methods of the subtype

Answer (score 3):

From [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation):

> A typical example that violates LSP is a Square class that derives
>   from a Rectangle class, assuming getter and setter methods exist for
>   both width and height. The Square class always assumes that the width
>   is equal with the height. If a Square object is used in a context
>   where a Rectangle is expected, unexpected behavior may occur because
>   the dimensions of a Square cannot (or rather should not) be modified
>   independently. **This problem cannot be easily fixed: if we can modify
>   the setter methods in the Square class so that they preserve the
>   Square invariant (i.e., keep the dimensions equal), then these methods
>   will weaken (violate) the postconditions for the Rectangle setters,
>   which state that dimensions can be modified independently.** Violations
>   of LSP, like this one, may or may not be a problem in practice,
>   depending on the postconditions or invariants that are actually
>   expected by the code that uses classes violating LSP. Mutability is a
>   key issue here. If Square and Rectangle had only getter methods (i.e.,
>   they were immutable objects), then no violation of LSP could occur.

So if you get rid of setters your solution no longer violates LSV.

Comment: +1 Perhaps you could give an explanation of why this complies with Liskov's substitution principle while the original does not.

Answer (score 0):

setWidth and setHeight are been defined in the parent class and according to Liskov substitution principle you should not modify the behaviour of the parent class in derivates classes. when Square inherits from Rectangle it make Square a derivate class which means that you should not modify any of those two methods (setWith and setHeight) originally defined in Rectangle class.

Violating the Liskov substitution principle produce undesirable effects. If the class hierarchy grows, it will become more and more complicated to know about the behaviour of the child classes. Secondly, unit tests for the superclass would never succeed for the subclass. The code that uses your type will have to have explicit knowledge of the internal workings of derived types to treat them differently

I have wrote a post explaining this principle and the consequences of violating it.

http://isaacjarquin.github.io/software/2016/09/27/solid-liskov-substitution-principle.html